# Taking and merging data from a tsv file

Tags: python, list, csv, spyder

In our data mining paper, we have to predict the intended side effects from benefit, side effect comments reviews in a 75/25 train/test.  The dataset is a .tsv file with columns urlDrugName, rating, effectiveness, condition, benefitReview, sideEffectReview and commentsReview.

My problem is this:

I want to read the data from the benefitReview, sideEffectReview and commentsReview columns and merge the text into one list/dict/lexicon (whatever is the best solution).  From there I can remove the stop words and stem or lemmatize the data etc before using classifications and start to move forward.

I can read the file, I just don't know or understand how to isolate those three columns and append it to a list or lexicon.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

A package that works well with columns and .csv files is the pandas package. This lets you create dataframes that are easy to manipulate.

https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're using in the rest of the project, you can use:

- The built-in [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module
- The [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package [CSV reader](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- The [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) package [txt reader](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

The first two talk about "comma-separated values", but they take an option to switch to tab-separated values; the third defaults to whitespace, which includes tabs, or you can also specify it explicitly (if your data contains spaces).

The built-in CSV library gives you the rows one by one, for use in a "for" loop. The Pandas and Numpy package CSV readers give you a Pandas dataframe or a Numpy array (respectively).

To decide between them, check what the other libraries you're using expect; it'll be easiest to load the data directly in the right form. If you're still not sure, Pandas is pretty good for exploring data.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it.

Basically I need to somehow pull out the data from those three columns and then process it and probably going to look at a CBOW and then maybe k-nearest neighbour and support vector model.

I have to use two classifications and then mess around with it to get the FPR values as best I can

I just find it hard to get started :(